# ScrollView including ListView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-scrollview

I would like to have a `ScrollView` that contains a `ListView`, which is obviously undesirable since a `ListView` has its own scroll bar.

Essentially I would like to have a `RelativeLayout` with a number of views forming the header of the page, followed by a `ListView`, similar to Facebook's profile page with the images followed by the feed.

If I simply put a `ListView` inside a `RelativeLayout` then only the `ListView` area is scrollable instead of the whole page.

Is there a way to do this without including the header (`RelativeLayout`) as the first element in the `ListView`?

Comment: There is a way but either way one of them will not scroll, try reconsidering your Layout structure

Comment: Could you elaborate? The ListView will be infinitely scrolled, I just need to have the header layout at the top of the view which will be included in the scrolling.

Comment: Let me add an answer to this question then.

Comment: and please if it solves your problem vote and mark as solved, if it doesn't or you didn't understand comment under it I'll reply. Thanks

Comment: Its a workaround, but not the solution I asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a method on ListView called addHeaderView. I can use this to add the RelativeLayout at the top. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I haven't done this myself, but I kinda know the trick to achieve your goal and give a sexy look to your layout.
First get rid of that ScrollView.
Then put a monitor(listener) on your ListView to detect how much your ListView has scrolled and consider a reasonable threshold to detect *.
Now what is * ? it is the time you should "Hide" or "slowly fade" your header items. when user scrolls down the ListView and reaches that threshold slowly fade or hide the header. Then again when user scrolls up use a threshold to decide when to make your header items visible.
As far as I know this is the idea. Also try checking github and android-arsenal I guess there should be a library for this that will ease your work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Use this class

    public class Helper {

       public static void getListViewSize(ListView myListView) {
           ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
           if (myListAdapter == null) {
    //           do nothing return null
               return;
           }
           //set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
           int totalHeight = 0;

           for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
               View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
               listItem.measure(0, 0);
               totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
           }
         //setting listview item in adapter
           ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
           params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
           myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
           // print height of adapter on log
           Log.i("height of listItem:", String.valueOf(totalHeight));
       }
    }

and in the activity class, use,

Helper.getListViewSize(ur listview name);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this Code.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout" >
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```